# How to get a video flow with Elixir/HTTPoison or Hackney?

Tags: elixir, multipart-mixed-replace, httpoison

I'm trying to get a stream from a cam using Elixir / HTTPoison and dump it into a file. 
Url is **x.x.x.x/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?duration=1&resolution=320x240**

Using the url in DHC (Chrome addon), i can have the following:

> Response 200 OK
>
> HEADERS Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Expires: Thu, 01 Dec
>   1994 16:00:00 GMT Connection: close Content-Type:
>   multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=myboundary X-Time-Offset:
>   62044.312573 pretty   COMPLETE REQUEST HEADERS Accept:        */* Accept-Encoding:        gzip, deflate, sdch
>   Accept-Language:      fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
>   Content-Type:     application/xml User-Agent:     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Note: XHR automatically adds
>   headers like Accept, Accept-Language, Cookie, User-Agent, etc.

Raw formatting the body is showing me a lot of binary jpeg image separated by a **--myboundary** thing.

> --myboundary
>
> Content-Type: image/jpeg
>
> Content-Length: 11848
>
> ����JFIF�� W�u]7W�u]7�� �2�̎TY"��C

Now, i want to try to get the same thing with Elixir.

```
  test "request headers from cam" do
    options = [hackney: [basic_auth: {"login","password"}]]
    {:ok, %HTTPoison.AsyncResponse{id: id}} = HTTPoison.get "http://x.x.x.x/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?duration=1&resolution=320x240",[], [stream_to: self, recv_timeout: :infinity, hackney: options]
    assert_receive %HTTPoison.AsyncStatus{id: ^id, code: 200}, 1_000
  end
```

I do have the following response,

```
  1) test request headers from cam (NewsequenceTest)
     test/newsequence_test.exs:9
     No message matching %HTTPoison.AsyncStatus{id: ^id, code: 200} after 1000ms.
     The following variables were pinned:
       id = #Reference<0.0.3.125>
     Process mailbox:
       %HTTPoison.AsyncStatus{code: 401, id: #Reference<0.0.3.125>}
       %HTTPoison.AsyncHeaders{headers: [{"Date", "Wed, 31 Aug 2016 06:47:00 GMT"}, {"Accept-Ranges", "bytes"}, {"Connection", "close"}, {"WWW-Authenticate", "Digest realm=\"AXIS_ACCC8E545922\", nonce=\"0000fa64Y50235919055a42f91d3dea744b10d2dab9653\", stale=FALSE, qop=\"auth\""}, {"WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"AXIS_ACCC8E545922\""}, {"Content-Length", "189"}, {"Content-Type", "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"}], id: #Reference<0.0.3.125>}
       %HTTPoison.AsyncChunk{chunk: "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>401 Unauthorized</TITLE></HEAD>\n<BODY><H1>401 Unauthorized</H1>\nYour client does not have permission to get URL /axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi from this server.\n</BODY></HTML>\n", id: #Reference<0.0.3.125>}
       %HTTPoison.AsyncEnd{id: #Reference<0.0.3.125>}
     stacktrace:
       test/newsequence_test.exs:12: (test)
```

I did try without basic auth with the same result.

I don't understand yet what it's happening with this auth error.
Sure i misunderstod something, can someone please enlighten me on this subject ?

Kind regards,

Pierre

Comment: Try with `options = [basic_auth: {"login","password"}]`.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks Dogbert !  
Any hint on how to proceed to properly get all the chunks into a file ?

Comment: Just in case, I did found the following to get the file. 
Thanks again Dogbert.
https://gitlab.amherst.edu/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=stream_to_file&group_id=&project_id=27&search_code=true&repository_ref=master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem here was that the code was calling:

```
HTTPoison.get(..., [], [..., hackney: [hackney: [basic_auth: {"login","password"}]]])
```

instead of:

```
HTTPoison.get(..., [], [..., hackney: [basic_auth: {"login","password"}]])
```

which was causing `hackney` to ignore them as it was trying to fetch `opts[:hackney][:basic_auth]` etc which were all `nil`.

The fix is to replace:

```
options = [hackney: [basic_auth: {"login","password"}]]
```

with

```
options = [basic_auth: {"login","password"}]
```