# Incorrect Mpeg file format after being transferred by Elixir/HTTPoison

Tags: elixir, mpeg, httpoison

Following my (dumb) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243409/how-to-get-a-video-flow-with-elixir-httpoison-or-hackney)
and reading [this](https://gitlab.amherst.edu/acdc/elixir-fcrepo-zipper/commit/2579ae069a9e47bec2f604dbd21103dc17b377f2?w=1)

I managed to connect to my cam, get the flow from it and dump it into an mpeg file. Here is the code for more clarity.

```
test "request headers from cam" do
    options = [basic_auth: {"LOGIN","PASSWORD"}, ibrowse: [{:save_response_to_file, true}]]
    {:ok, %HTTPoison.AsyncResponse{id: id}} = HTTPoison.get "http://x.x.x.x/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?duration=2&resolution=320x240",[], [stream_to: self, recv_timeout: :infinity, hackney: options
                                                                                                                                              ]
    {:ok, file} = File.open("/tmp/test.mpeg", [:write])
    retour = stream_to_file(id,file)
    send self,{:retour, retour}
    assert_receive {:retour ,:ok}, 10_000
  end

  defp stream_to_file(id, output) do
    receive do
     %HTTPoison.AsyncStatus{ id: ^id, code: code} ->
        IO.puts " AsyncStatus"
        stream_to_file(id,output)
      %HTTPoison.AsyncHeaders{ id: ^id} ->
        stream_to_file(id,output)
      %HTTPoison.AsyncEnd{ id: ^id} ->
        IO.puts " AsyncEnd received"
        :ok
      %HTTPoison.AsyncChunk{id: ^id, chunk: chunk} ->
        IO.binwrite(output, chunk)
        stream_to_file(id, output)
    end
  end
```

Test is running fine, a file is generated as expected but when i try to read it (using a couple of player), i can surreptitiously see one image from the cam and it stops rightafter.

Size (depending on parameters) can be important and when editing the file, i can clearly guess these are successive Jpeg files.

Here is the beginning of the file.

> --myboundary Content-Type: image/jpeg Content-Length: 9609
>
> ˇÿˇ‡JFIFˇ˛ W»XW»Xˇ˛ ß2¨ÃéTY"ˇ€C

It tried to play with several parameters without success, it looks like the file is not recognized as a mpeg file.

Any thoughts ? 
Regards,
Pierre

Comment: What guarantees the original order of the chunks (bytes) as they are written to file with `stream_to_file`?

Comment: Tks for helping. Nothing i'm afraid. Only thing i can check with iHex is that all jpeg files inside are clearly separated by --myboundary
I did copy a random block between to --myboundary separators, put it within a file and i had a correct image.

Comment: MediaInfo doesn't seems to be able to extract any info from it. Did i forget to  write header or something ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Elixir/HTTPoison or HTTPotion wasn't responsible.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG)

> In multimedia, Motion JPEG (M-JPEG or MJPEG) is a video compression
>   format in which each video frame or interlaced field of a digital
>   video sequence is compressed separately as a JPEG image. Originally
>   developed for multimedia PC applications, M-JPEG is now used by
>   video-capture devices such as digital cameras, IP cameras, and
>   webcams; and by non-linear video editing systems. It is natively
>   supported by the QuickTime Player, the PlayStation console, and web
>   browsers such as Safari, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Microsoft
>   Edge.

I tried to manually extract Jpeg file from original file itself, and after a successfully attempt, quickest way i've found, was to use python (Can be slightly different if you are not in 2.7 eg : cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) and [OpenCv](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html).

```
import cv2
import urllib 
import numpy as np
import os

stream=open('./example.mjpg','rb')
sizemax = os.path.getsize("./example.mjpg")
bytes=''
allbytes = 0
nimage = 0
while nimage * 1024 < sizemax:
     nimage= nimage + 1
     bytes+=stream.read(1024)
     allbytes += allbytes + 1024
     a = bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
     b = bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
     if a!=-1 and b!=-1:
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
        bytes= bytes[b+2:]
        i = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow('i',i)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) ==27:
            exit(0)
```

Regards,

Pierre